# My script wont redirect to my other classes?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, windows-10, command-prompt

I created a variable and I assigned it to an input. But no matter what I input it just redirects back to :EditUser. I don't know why it is doing that.

This is what my code is. Can someone tell me why it wont direct to the other classes. This is the only redirection in my script that won't work.

```
:EditUser
cls
echo You chose to edit a user
echo ========================
echo 1. Change Password
echo 2. Change Account Type
echo 3. Go back to Users
echo.
set /p CHOICE6=What do you want to do?
if CHOICE6==1 goto PassChange
if CHOICE6==2 goto PrivChange
if CHOICE6==3 goto Users
goto EditUser
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot To wrap your variables with `%` to make recognise them as such. It should be `%CHOICE6%` Additionally, you should either enclose the if statement query in double quotes to eliminate possible whitespace `if "%CHOICE6%"=="1"` or even better seeing as it is numerical, use `if %CHOICE6% equ 1`

Anyway, seeing as you are working with the obvious of `Choice` then just use choice instead of `set /p`

```
:EditUser
cls
echo You chose to edit a user
choice /c 123 /m "Select (1) Change Password (2) change account type (3) go back to users"
goto :opt%errorlevel%

:opt1
echo change password stuff here.
goto :eof

:opt2
echo change account type stuff goes here
goto :eof

:opt3
goto :users
goto :eof
```

So what Really happens is that we just goto a label starting with `opt` appended by the errorlevel returned by `choice`

It also only allows one of the alphanumeric values entered only, anything else you type will not be acted on. So in this case, only 1, 2 or 3 will be acted on by cmd.

see `choice /?` for more detail.

Also, if you want to retain your echo layout and not have the options in one line, add the echo's and remove the message `/m` swirtch from `choice`:

```
:EditUser
cls
echo You chose to edit a user
echo ========================
echo 1. Change Password
echo 2. Change Account Type
echo 3. Go back to Users
echo(
choice /c 123
goto :opt%errorlevel%

:opt1
echo change password stuff here.
goto :eof

:opt2
echo change account type stuff goes here
goto :eof

:opt3
goto :users?
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot to wrap your variables in `%` when using them.

however, you woudl do well to use the good practice of wrapping SET commands in `"` as well

Also, you could simplify your life a little by using choice, although it's still possible to get the choice to error out so YMMV

```
:EditUser
cls
echo.You chose to edit a user
echo.========================
echo.1. Change Password
echo.2. Change Account Type
echo.3. Go back to Users
echo.
set /p "CHOICE6=What do you want to do? "
IF %CHOICE6% EQU 1 goto :PassChange
IF %CHOICE6% EQU 2 goto :PrivChange
if %CHOICE6% EQU 3 goto :Users
goto :EditUser
```

That said for best practice you should write functions using `CALL` and you can return choice variables to the main code to act on or do it from within the function as suites best.

`CALL` is "SAFE" as it will return to the current point of execution on a function or script ending, and you can write scripts in a better practice.

```
REM Example main function
:Main
  REM ...

  REM Call Edit User, Specify a variable name to be returned
  CALL :EditUser "CALL_THIS"

  REM Call the function we chose in the :Edit User Function and was returned to us here, and may be :PassChange, :PrivChange, :Users
  CALL %CALL_THIS% 

  REM ...
GOTO :EOF

:EditUser
REM Clear the Variable Provided to the fucntion to be returned
SET "%~1="
REM Clear the Choice
SET "CHOICE6="
cls
echo.You chose to edit a user
echo.========================
echo.1. Change Password
echo.2. Change Account Type
echo.3. Go back to Users
echo.
CHOICE /C 123 /N /M "What do you want to do? "
SET "CHOICE6=%ERRORLEVEL%"
REM Check an arbitrary number of choices without having to write a full IF on each.
FOR %%_ IN (
 1:PassChange
 2:PrivChange
 3:Users
) DO (

  REM Split choices to test them:
  FOR /F "Tokens=12 Delims=:" %%A (
    IF %%A EQU %CHOICE6% (

      REM Set The Variable given the function '%1' to a value to return to Main script when the Choice was matched.
      SET "%~1=:%%B"
    )
  )

  REM Exit Function when %~1 is defined.
  IF DEFINED %~1 GOTO :EOF
)

REM Show screen again when not matched
GOTO :EditUser
```

Yes more code but as you can see now you have a reusable function that could be called an arbitrary number of times as your code requires, and allows the outer code whether in another function or in the main code to execute the next called function.

But even in places where you don't need to call another function you can use the loop logic here to store a list of choices and evaluate them without having to re-type all fo your if statements.

Further, you could write that more generically too and not have any multiple-choice variables re-using the choice function logic each time as the callable function, and allowing you to write less repetitive and smaller footprint code.